# Best pattern to reduce excessive conditionals

Tags: actionscript-3, design-patterns, refactoring

I have the following code for a game that manages display patterns for items by randomly deciding on one, creating the items based on the pattern chosen and then animating them.

The problem is that cleaning code and managing changes can be cumbersome due to the sheer size, I have been studying design patterns lately and I was wondering which would be the best one to apply here, so far I have considered strategy and command as possible options

"The strategy pattern is used to create an interchangeable family of algorithms from which the required process is chosen at run-time." Seems like something I could use to apply the positioning of the items depending on the pattern selected.

And by looking at previous questions here when asked about reducing the amount of if/elses the command pattern came up quite a bit.

" The command pattern is used to express a request, including the call to be made and all of its required parameters, in a command object. The command may then be executed immediately or held for later use."

Still, I don't know if I may be finding relevance where there is not, so I thought I'd ask if such patterns can be applied to the following scenarios.

Below is the relevant code, I'm specially interested in learning about this because almost the same code is repeated for enemies.

```
        /**
     * Set items pattern.  
     * 
     */

    private function setItemsPattern():void
    {
        // Change until enough flight distance has been accumulated.
        if (patternChange > 0)
        {
            patternChange -= playerSpeed * elapsed;
        }
        else
        {
            // As the player moves, change item patterns.

            if ( Math.random() < 0.7 )
            {
                // If  < normal item chance (0.7), get a random pattern.
                pattern = Math.ceil(Math.random() * 4); 
            }
            else
            {
                // If random number is > normal item chance (0.3), create special item.

                pattern = Math.ceil(Math.random() * 2) + 9;
            }

            if (pattern == GameConstants.ITEM_PATTERN_VERTICAL)  
            {
                // Vertical 
                patternStep = 15;
                patternChange = Math.random() * 500 + 500;
            }
            else if (pattern == GameConstants.ITEM_PATTERN_HORIZONTAL)
            {
                // Horizontal 
                patternOnce = true;
                patternStep = 40;
                patternChange = patternGap * Math.random() * 3 + 5;
            }
            else if (pattern == GameConstants.ITEM_PATTERN_ZIGZAG)
            {
                // ZigZag
                patternStep = Math.round(Math.random() * 2 + 2) * 10;
                if ( Math.random() > 0.5 )
                {
                    patternDirection *= -1;
                }
                patternChange = Math.random() * 800 + 800;
            }
            else if (pattern == GameConstants.ITEM_PATTERN_RANDOM)
            {
                // Random 
                patternStep = Math.round(Math.random() * 3 + 2) * 50;
                patternChange = Math.random() * 400 + 400;
            }
            else  
            {
                patternChange = 0;
            }
        }
    }

    /**
     * Creates items - called by createPattern() 
     * 
     */

    private function createItems():void
    {

        var itemToTrack:Item;

        switch (pattern)
        {
            case GameConstants.ITEM_PATTERN_HORIZONTAL:
                // Horizontal.
                if (Math.random() > 0.9)
                {
                    // Asignes items not too close to border.
                    patternPosY = Math.floor(Math.random() * (gameArea.bottom - gameArea.top + 1)) + gameArea.top;
                }


                itemToTrack = itemFactory.getItem(GameConstants.ITEM_TYPE_1);
                this.addChild(itemToTrack);


                // Sets pos
                itemToTrack.x = stage.stageWidth + itemToTrack.width ;
                itemToTrack.y = patternPosY;

                // Marks item for animation
                itemsToAnimate.push(itemToTrack);


                break;

            case GameConstants.ITEM_PATTERN_VERTICAL:
                // Vertical
                if (patternOnce == true)
                {
                    patternOnce = false;


                    patternPosY = Math.floor(Math.random() * (gameArea.bottom - gameArea.top + 1)) + gameArea.top;


                    patternLength = (Math.random() * 0.4 + 0.4) * stage.stageHeight;
                }


                patternPosYstart = patternPosY; 


                while (patternPosYstart + patternStep < patternPosY + patternLength && patternPosYstart + patternStep < stage.stageHeight * 0.8)
                {


                    itemToTrack = itemFactory.getItem(GameConstants.ITEM_TYPE_1);
                    this.addChild(itemToTrack);



                    itemToTrack.x = stage.stageWidth + itemToTrack.width;
                    itemToTrack.y = patternPosYstart;


                    itemsToAnimate.push(itemToTrack)


                    patternPosYstart += patternStep;
                }
                break;

            case GameConstants.ITEM_PATTERN_ZIGZAG:
                // ZigZag

                if (patternDirection == 1 && patternPosY > gameArea.bottom - 50)
                {
                    patternDirection = -1;
                }
                else if ( patternDirection == -1 && patternPosY < gameArea.top )
                {
                    patternDirection = 1;
                }

                if (patternPosY >= gameArea.top && patternPosY <= gameArea.bottom)
                {


                    itemToTrack = itemFactory.getItem(GameConstants.ITEM_TYPE_1);
                    this.addChild(itemToTrack);


                    itemToTrack.x = stage.stageWidth + itemToTrack.width;
                    itemToTrack.y = patternPosY;


                    itemsToAnimate.push(itemToTrack)


                    patternPosY += patternStep * patternDirection;
                }
                else
                {
                    patternPosY = gameArea.top;
                }

                break;

            case GameConstants.ITEM_PATTERN_RANDOM:

                // Random, creates N amount of items on screen.
                if (Math.random() > 0.3)
                {

                    patternPosY = Math.floor(Math.random() * (gameArea.bottom - gameArea.top + 1)) + gameArea.top;


                    while (patternPosY + patternStep < gameArea.bottom)
                    {


                        itemToTrack = itemFactory.getItem(GameConstants.ITEM_TYPE_1);
                        this.addChild(itemToTrack);


                        itemToTrack.x = stage.stageWidth + itemToTrack.width;
                        itemToTrack.y = patternPosY;


                        itemsToAnimate.push(itemToTrack)


                        patternPosY += Math.round(Math.random() * 100 + 100);
                    }
                }

                break;

            case GameConstants.ITEM_PATTERN_SPEED:

                // special item

                patternPosY = Math.floor(Math.random() * (gameArea.bottom - gameArea.top + 1)) + gameArea.top;


                itemToTrack = itemFactory.getItem(GameConstants.ITEM_TYPE_MANA);
                this.addChild(itemToTrack);


                itemToTrack.x = stage.stageWidth + itemToTrack.width;
                itemToTrack.y = patternPosY;


                itemsToAnimate.push(itemToTrack);

                break;

            case GameConstants.ITEM_PATTERN_STR:

            // special item

                patternPosY = Math.floor(Math.random() * (gameArea.bottom - gameArea.top + 1)) + gameArea.top;



                itemToTrack = itemFactory.getItem(GameConstants.ITEM_TYPE_REFERENCIA);
                this.addChild(itemToTrack);

                itemToTrack.x = stage.stageWidth + itemToTrack.width;
                itemToTrack.y = patternPosY;


                itemsToAnimate.push(itemToTrack);

                break;


        }
    }


    /**
     * Animates the vector itemsToAnimate. 
     * 
     */


    private function animateItems():void
    {

            var itemToTrack:Item;

            for(var i:uint = 0;i<itemsToAnimate.length;i++)
            {
                itemToTrack = itemsToAnimate[i];

                if (itemToTrack != null)
                {

                    if (referencia > 0 && itemToTrack.itemType <= GameConstants.ITEM_TYPE_REFERENCIA)
                    {

                        itemToTrack.x -= (itemToTrack.x - brujaX) * 0.2;
                        itemToTrack.y -= (itemToTrack.y - brujaY) * 0.2;


                    }
                    else
                    {

                        itemToTrack.x -= playerSpeed * elapsed; 
                    }


                    if (itemToTrack.x < -80 || gameState == GameConstants.GAME_STATE_OVER)
                    {
                        disposeItemTemporarily(i, itemToTrack);
                    }
                    else
                    {

                        brujaItem_xDist = itemToTrack.x - brujaX;
                        brujaItem_yDist = itemToTrack.y - brujaY;
                        brujaItem_sqDist = brujaItem_xDist * brujaItem_xDist + brujaItem_yDist * brujaItem_yDist;

                        if (brujaItem_sqDist < 5000)
                        {

                            if (itemToTrack.itemType == GameConstants.ITEM_TYPE_1)
                            {
                                scoreItems += itemToTrack.itemType;
                                hud.itemScore = scoreItems;
                                if (!Sounds.muted) Sounds.sndPag.play();
                            }

                            else if (itemToTrack.itemType == GameConstants.ITEM_TYPE_MANA) 
                            {

                                scoreItems += 1;


                                mana = 5;
                                if (isHardwareRendering) particleMana.start(mana);

                                if (!Sounds.muted) Sounds.sndMana.play();
                                if (!Sounds.muted) Sounds.sndRisa.play();
                            }

                            else if (itemToTrack.itemType == GameConstants.ITEM_TYPE_REFERENCIA) 
                            {

                                scoreItems += 1;

                                referencia = 20;
                                partRef = 0.5;
                                if (isHardwareRendering) particleRef.start(partRef);

                                playRandomRef();

                            }

                            if(referencia > 0){referencia--;}


                            disposeItemTemporarily(i, itemToTrack);
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: Many chained conditionals smells like something that could be solved by either Strategy or maybe State pattern if there is some relation of causality between the animations.

Structuraly, Command and Strategy are very similar, the difference is that Command encapsulates a single action, while Strategy does the same for algorithms.

Comment: First, don't use magic numbers (1, 2, 3, 4) but define some constants or use an enumeration. Second, before you look at a pattern, try some refactoring. I'm pretty sure you can apply this one http://refactoring.com/catalog/replaceConditionalWithPolymorphism.html

Comment: @Fuhrmanator Thanks I 'll look into that as well. Also i do use constants in other places like SPECIAL_ITEM but for some reason I never thought of using PATTERN_VERTICAl for example. I truly aprecciate you pointing this obvious thing to me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your function setItemsPattern and createItems both contain a switch-case statement, so you could create a base class contains two functions hanlde the switch-case work.

For example, you get the base class like this

```
Class BaseBehavior
{

    //if the variable shouldn't be accessed by other class, change public to protected
    public var patternOnce:Boolean;

    public var patternStep:int;

    public var patternChange:int;

    public var patternDirection:int;

    public var itemToTrack:Object;

    public var gameArea:Object;

    //used in setItemsPattern function 
    public function initPatternData():void {};

   //used in createItems function 
    public function createItems():void {};

    public function dispose():void {};
}
```

And here is the vertical class

```
Class VerticalBehavior extends BaseBehavior
{

    override public function initPatternData():void
    {
          patternStep = 15;

          patternChange = Math.random() * 500 + 500;
    }

    override public function createItems():void 
    {
         if (Math.random() > 0.9)
         {
              // Asignes items not too close to border.
             patternPosY = Math.floor(Math.random() * (gameArea.bottom - gameArea.top + 1)) + gameArea.top;
         }

         itemToTrack = itemFactory.getItem(GameConstants.ITEM_TYPE_1);

         // Sets pos
         itemToTrack.x = stage.stageWidth + itemToTrack.width ;
         itemToTrack.y = patternPosY;
    }

}
```

Other sub classes are most same.

Now you need a factory class to  create the sub class

```
 Class BehaviorFactory
 {

      public static function create(type:int):BaseBehavior
      {
           switch(type)
           {
              case 1://vertical
                  return new VerticalBehavior();

              case 2:
                  return ...

               ...
           }
      }
 }
```

After these work, you can use them in your old logic code

```
private var behavior:BaseBehavior;

private function setItemsPattern():void
{
    if (behavior && behavior.patternChange > 0)
    {
        behavior.patternChange -= playerSpeed * elapsed;
    }
    else
    {
        // As the player moves, change item patterns.

        if ( Math.random() < 0.7 )
        {
            // If  < normal item chance (0.7), get a random pattern.
            pattern = Math.ceil(Math.random() * 4); 
        }
        else
        {
            // If random number is > normal item chance (0.3), create special item.

            pattern = Math.ceil(Math.random() * 2) + 9;
        }

        //here to create the sub class

        //dispose old behavior
        if (behavior)
        {
             behavior.dispose();
        }

        behavior = BehaviorFactory.create(pattern);

}


private function createItems():voidh
{
     //you may check behavior is null here
     var itemToTrack:Item = behavior.createItems();

      this.addChild(itemToTrack);

      // Marks item for animation
      itemsToAnimate.push(itemToTrack);
}
```

At last, if you want add a new type, you just need to create a sub behavior class and add it to the factory class.But be careful if the variables in the behavior increase too many, you may need to use composition class.

Comment: So basically this is a interface/parent class that defines the base behavior for the patterns, then each sub-class extends this behavior to suit each pattern's needs.

Then on the class that uses this patterns a behavior is created via a factory depending on the pattern (which as stated on a comment above would now be a constant) selected at random.

I suppose putting all this on a package would be better? I don't want to have so many classes that do the same but slightly different (if that even makes sense). I'll look into the composite pattern as well.

Comment: Imagine that you got more functions with switch-case here, like 7, It will be hard for other people to read your code and work on it, they must change all the switch-case to make it work.

Comment: I understand, I'll accept your answer thanks for taking the time!